# Retrieve rows that have a first entry in 2014 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I want to retrieve all rows from a table that have their first entry on or after 01/01/2014 but no later than 31/12/2014

Example of the table:

```
OID    FK_OID    Treatment    Trt_DATE
 1      100       19304       2011-05-24
 2      100       19304       2011-08-01
 3      100       19306       2014-03-05
 4      200       19305       2012-02-02
 5      300       19308       2014-01-20
 6      400       19308       2014-06-06
```

For example.  I would like to pull all entries that have STARTED treatment in 2014.  So above i would to extract FK_OID's 300 and 400 because their first entry is in 2014, but i would like to omit FK_OID 100 because they have 2 entries prior to 2014.

How do i go about this?  I can extract all entries within a date range etc but that brings back all entries for that date and doesn't omit anyone who has an entry prior to the start of the date range.  It just returns their first entry in 2014.

For the ones who need to see that i have tried something.  See below.
I am not an experienced coder and this is the best i can get because i don't have the knowledge.

```
SELECT 
    mod,
    (select NHSNum from person p
    WHERE
        p.oid = t.fk_oid) as 'NHS'
    FROM
        timeline t
    Where trt_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
    ORDER BY trt_date ASC
```

This returns every treatment for 2014 regardless of whether it is the first ever one for that person.  I want to omit anyone from this list who has had treatment before 01/01/2014 as well as only return the first treatment per person.  For example, this code returns all treatments for all people in 2014.  I only want their first one and only if it is their first one ever.

Thanks.

Comment: Turns out it didnt come out ok.  Will work on it.  Please bear with me.

Comment: Just added 4 spaces in front of the table there. Or us Select section and CTRL+K

Comment: how about `... where year(Trt_DATE)=2014 and fk_oid<>100 order by Trt_DATE limit 1`  or not limit 1

Comment: Show us the query you have tried to write

Comment: @Drew This bit _but i would like to omit FK_OID 100 because they have 2 entries prior to 2014._ makes it a bit more complicated

Comment: you actually read the question ?  :P

Comment: @Drew Was that a suprised statement or a question?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Thanks...done.

Comment: @Drew Pulling an all nighter or do you always work in the _wee small hours_

Comment: @Drew - Thanks but this pulls back the first entry in 2014 for everyone.  I only want the people who do not have an entry before 2014.

Comment: the plot thickens on this op question the more I read

Comment: Not sure why the down arrow.....I dont have the code for it because i know the code i have is wrong.  It is a simple select * from table where TRT_DATE between 2014-01-01 and 2014-12-31.  Not a lot else to explain and i apologised for the formatting which is now fixed.....

Comment: Mike, Not my DV. The DV is probably because you did not add the query. You are supposed to show that you have at least tried some thing and are not asking a question that is basically a spec for a _write it for me question_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a few years a experience with this, i decided to revisit it.  The solution i now use regularly is:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2
FROM MyTable AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable AS t2
  ON t1.fkoid = t2.fkoid 
  AND (t1.date > t2.date 
  OR (t1.date = t2.date AND t1.oid > t2.oId))
WHERE t2.fkoid IS NULL and t1.date >= '2014-01-01'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 create table aThing
 (   oid int auto_increment primary key,
     fk_oid int not null,
     treatment int not null,
     trt_date date not null
 );

 insert aThing (fk_oid,treatment,trt_date) values
 (100,       19304,       '2011-05-24'),
 (100,       19304,       '2011-08-01'),
 (100,       19306,       '2014-03-05'),
 (200,       19305,       '2012-02-02'),
 (300,       19308,       '2014-01-20'),
 (400,       19308,       '2014-06-06');


select fk_oid,dt 
from 
(   select fk_oid,min(trt_date) as dt 
    from aThing 
    group by fk_oid 
) xDerived 
where year(dt)=2014;
+--------+------------+
| fk_oid | dt         |
+--------+------------+
|    300 | 2014-01-20 |
|    400 | 2014-06-06 |
+--------+------------+
```

The inner part, the nested one, become a derived table, and is given a name xDerived. This means that even though it is just a result set, by making it a derived table, it can be referred to by name. So it is not a physical table, but a derived one, or virtual one.

So that derived table is a very simple group by with an aggregate function. It says, for every `fk_oid`, bring back one row and only 1 row, with its minimum value for `trt_date.`

So if you have 10 million rows in that table called `aThing`, but only 17 distinct values for `fk_oid`, it will return only 17 rows. Each row being the minimum of `trt_date` for its `fk_oid`.

So now that that is achieved, the outer wrapper says just show me those two columns (but with a year check). There is a complicated to explain reason why I had to do that, so I will try to do it here.

But I might need a little time to explain it well, so bear with me.

This will be a shortcut way to say it. I had to get the `min` into an alias, and I only had access to that alias if resolved in a derived table, to cleanse it so to speak, and then access it with an outer wrapper.

An alias of aggregate column, like `as dt`, is not available (as a pseudo like column name which is what an alias is) ... it is not available in a `where` clause. But by wrapping it in a derived table name, I cleanse it so to speak, and then I can access it in a where clause.

So I can't access it directly in its own query in the where clause, but when I wrap it in an envelope (a derived table), I can access it on the outside.

I will try better to explain it later, maybe, but I would have to show alternative attempts to gain access to results, and the syntax errors that would result.

Comment: Thanks - Would you mind offering a little explanation to it please?  As mentioned above i am a relative beginner and struggling to learn this with VERY little support from anyone.

Comment: yes sorry, I will do an edit. It was like really late and I didn't mean to leave it like that. I fell asleep

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant solution, but this seems to satisfy the requirement...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT fk_oid
            , MIN(trt_date) min_date
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY fk_oid
       HAVING min_date > '2014-01-01'
     ) a
    ON a.fk_oid = x.fk_oid
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table b
    ON b.fk_oid = a.fk_oid
   AND b.trt_date > '2014-12-31'
 WHERE b.oid IS NULL;
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what my_table b is please?  I am only querying one table so am confused by the join.  Thanks

Comment: 'a' is an alias for the subquery. 'b' and 'x' are both aliases for various instances of the core table. Joining a table to itself is perfectly normal.

Comment: Ah ha - Thank you.  Makes a bit more sense now.  I will need a little tweaking though i think because it has returned far too many results.  So may not be what i was looking for.

Comment: Maybe you don't really want to retrieve 'all rows [that have fk_oids that satisfy the criteria]'. Maybe you only want the rows that *actually* satisfy the criteria. In which case you don't really need the first instance ('x')